# Low-Drop Voltage Tracker Working

Tags: power-supply, power, ldo

Could you please explain how a 'Low-Drop Voltage Tracker' IC works. For example take  the     TLE4250G from Infineon. what is the difference between LDO and Low-Drop Voltage Tracker .
Regards
Hari.

Comment: It's also worth looking at [fig 3](http://www.icbase.com/File/PDF/IFT/IFT00251108.pdf) in its datasheet to see how it would be typically used, i.e. you can leverage directly or indirectly the voltage reference from a [presumably more expensive LDO], but you still have over-temperature protection and so forth all in one package.

Answer (score 3):

They are quite similar.

I hope you're familiar how a LDO regulator works, so I don't have to explain that here. Remember that a normal LDO consists of a voltage reference, an error amplifier and a pass element (transistor).

A voltage tracker is the same except that it does not contain the voltage reference. Instead you supply the reference voltage externally.

You can think about them as voltage followers with built-in goodies like overcurrent, temperature and short circuit protection.

And to answer the possible follow-up question right away: "Why do I want a voltage tracker instead of just using a cheap opamp as a voltage follower": A voltage tracker has no problems driving capacitive loads which you need in most voltage supply applications. Opamps on the other hand rarely tolerate more than a few hundret picofarads at their output. They aren't suitable to supply voltage for micro-controllers due to the lack to drive bypass capacitors for example. Voltage trackers on the other hand are.

Answer (score 2):

A voltage tracker is a "simpler" LDO, it has no integrated reference voltage to which is regulates the output voltage.

Instead it regulates the output voltage to match the voltage of the adjust pin.

Basically it is a beefed up version of an op-amp voltage follower, but it's optimized to drive higher loads.

This particular part also offers optimizations for automotive use (very rough environment with all sort of spikes). In the example they use it to switch on and off a sensor with the GPIO pin of the MCU, because it can't drive those currents and with all the protection circuitry a not integrated solution gets bigger.